# Python instant messaging program fails to connect with errno 111

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, instant-messaging

I am trying to implement a simple TCP instant messaging program in Python using the socket module.  When I use the value returned by `socket.gethostname()` in `connect()`, the client works perfectly fine when connecting to the IM server running on localhost.  However, the client returns errno 111 (Connection refused) when I use the value returned by `socket.gethostbyname("localhost")`.  Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Probably the server isn't listening on `localhost`. You can test this by using netcat or telnet—e.g., `nc localhost 111`. Without knowing anything about your server beyond a brief mention, it's impossible to diagnose, but my first guess would be that you're doing a `bind((gethostname(), 111))` instead of `bind('', 111)`, or something equivalent.

Comment: OK, I'll turn it into an answer, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a 111 when trying to `connect`, that generally means nothing is listening at that host and port.

It's usually easier to check this with a one-liner using [`netcat`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) (which you probably have built-in on any platform but Windows, and can get easily if you don't), or `telnet` if you must:

```
abarnert$ nc -v localhost 111
nc: connect to localhost port 111 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connect to localhost port 111 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connect to localhost port 111 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

Since netcat couldn't connect, the problem isn't your Python client, it really is that there's nothing to connect to.

This means your server isn't listening on localhost:111.

Without knowing anything about your server beyond a brief mention, it's impossible to diagnose, but my first guess would be that you're doing a `bind((gethostname(), 111))`, which means it ends up listening only on, say, `10.0.0.3:111`.

If you want to listen on all hosts and interfaces, there are fancy ways to specify that, but the easiest way is:

```
serversocket.bind(('', 111))
```